# tkinter: How to create "N" Entry widgets and insert string-lines into them?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm stuck on a little problem and I need help please.

I start by reading my variable X and I count the number of lines N.

Then I create N `Entry` widgets.

So my problem is that I would like to insert each line in each entry.
I can't find a solution, maybe I should create a list with the entries but then I don't know what to do? :/

```
all_my_entries = []
X = str(fiche_pat_table[5])
N= len(x.split('\n'))

for y in range(N):
  tk.Label(my_frame, text="antécédent", bg="#F5CBA7").grid(row=y+1, column=0)
  my_entry= tk.Entry(my_frame)
  my_entry.grid(row=y+1, column=1)
  all_my_entries.append(my_entry)
```

hi i could edit my code here :/

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

all_atcd_entries=[]
x = str("line1 \n line2")
n_atcd = len(x.split('\n'))
ligne_atcd = x.split('\n')

for y in range(n_atcd):
    tk.Label(root, text="antécédent", bg="#F5CBA7").grid(row=y + 1, column=0)
    eatcd_deux = tk.Entry(root)
    eatcd_deux.grid(row=y + 1, column=1)
    all_atcd_entries.append(eatcd_deux)

##### i tired that #####
for entrie in all_atcd_entries:
    for ligne in ligne_atcd:
        entrie.insert(0, ligne)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can insert a string into an `Entry` widget by calling its [`insert()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html#entry-index) method. i.e. `my_entry.insert(0, "abc")`.

Comment: hi, i know that, but what to do when i dont know the number of entry and line ... so i tried something like that :     `for entrie in all_atcd_entries:
                                                       for ligne in ligne_atcd:
                                                               entrie.insert(0, ligne) `  but it doesnt work

Comment: Provide the code for runnable [mre] **in your question** and I'll show you.

Comment: sorry im not familiar with stackoverflow and i had this message "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. " dont even know why. and i duno how to post a code in comment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to pair each entry with the corresponding line:

```
rom tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

all_atcd_entries=[]
x = str("line1 \n line2")
n_atcd = len(x.split('\n'))
ligne_atcd = x.split('\n')

for y in range(n_atcd):
    tk.Label(root, text="antécédent", bg="#F5CBA7").grid(row=y + 1, column=0)
    eatcd_deux = tk.Entry(root)
    eatcd_deux.grid(row=y + 1, column=1)
    all_atcd_entries.append(eatcd_deux)

for entrie, ligne in zip(all_atcd_entries, ligne_atcd):
    entrie.insert(0, ligne)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You got typo error. rom tkinter import *  to from tkinter import *